# ANSI Colors not showing where they are supposed to show

Tags: python-3.x, ansi-escape

I would like for the entire text that pops up when you use the help() function to be affected by the color code that I used, but instead when I run the script the only part that is affected by said color code is a "None" text below the help() result

```py
print(f'\033[34m {help("for")} \033[m')
```

[This is the single line of code and how it looks in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAosD.png)

Comment: what version of python are you using? I noticed the syntax changes in 3.6+ here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python

Comment: I'm using python 3.8, yeah, that Syntax works great in every ocasion (yet) but this one.

it seems to not recognize the output of the help() function as the intended text to apply its effects when you put it all in the same line, not really sure why tho

Comment: It's possible that the way python performs string interpolation that the formatting happens  before the value is inserted, but that's just a guess based on what you are seeing happen. What happens if you allow help to evaluate, capture that value, then use `print(f'\033[34m {theHelpValue} \033[m')`?

Comment: Interesting guess, but unfortunately the result is still the same, I tried with this code

    value = help('for')
    print(f'\033[41m {value} \033[m')

Comment: One last suggestion - what about string concatenation instead of interpolation: `print('\033[34m' + help("for") + '\033[m')` (I don't know python offhand so thats sort of pseudo code)

Comment: Still the same, only coloring the "None" text that returns after the result
python really doesn't seem to like the idea of coloring the help() function in a compact way hahaha

Answer (score 1):

The (pretty simple) workaround that I found is to just print the color codes on separate lines

Example:

```
print('\033[41m')
print(help('for'))
print('\033[m')
```

That code will make it so the output of the help('for') function has a red background

Comment: Why `print(help(...))`? `help` writes to stdout on it's own, so it's equivalent to writing `help(...); print(None)`. You can just `help(...)` on its own.